# Glassfish not in list of installed bundles

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, netbeans-8

Just beginning with Java web dev and my project builds then fails with the following error:

WARNING: Can not start bundle file:/Users/Ryan/GlassFish_Server/glassfish/modules/core.jar because it is not contained in the list of installed bundles.

I tried clearing any port-consuming applications but it did not fix the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

In Netbeans IDE: menu bar -> Netbeans -> Preferences -> General -> Proxy Settings -> Select No Proxy.

Click Test Connection & Apply

Answer (score 0):

open your network preferences > Select your wifi > Advanced > proxies tab > check Auto proxy Discovery, Automatic Proxy configuration, web proxy(http)

Now, go to your Netbeans preferences > General > select use system proxy>
reload > test connection > then it should have a green check mark next to it if connection successful.

Finally, go to Clean & build your Applications in netbeans and run